# Qualtrics code for text entry

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

Does anyone have (or can help) code that will enable respondents  move between text entry questions without having to use the mouse. My survey is set up in qualtrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the following code to the first text question on a page, it will allow for immediate typing in the first text input field.  Then the tab key will move to subsequent fields.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    $(this.questionId).select('.InputText').first().focus();
});
```